# Firemonkey StringGrid wont send back data to Snapserver under android

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, stringgrid

I'm developing an android app in FM, NO BINDING(slow etc), I manually fill the data into string grid and manual update the records.
The compiled 32-bit app works well but under android it wont UPDATE the records.
Its communicate over DataSnap server everything is good under 32-bit.

Do You have any idea why wont update the records under android.

UPDATE (but its under testing):
I dont know what was the problem yesterday but its working today, the only one thing what i changed is the ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0); to ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(-1);

Regards Tamas

Here is my StringGrid insert code:

```
var
  ir: integer;
  cr, cc: integer;
begin
  ClientDataSet1.First;
  ir := 0;

  for cc := 0 to Grid_term.RowCount do
  begin
    for cr := 0 to Grid_term.ColumnCount do
    begin
      Grid_term.Cells[cc, cr] := '';
    end;
  end;

  while not ClientDataSet1.Eof do
  begin
    Grid_term.Cells[0, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('torzs_id').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[1, ir] := ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('torzs_nev').AsString;
    Grid_term.Cells[2, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('muszak_id').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[3, ir] := ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('gep_nev').AsString;
    Grid_term.Cells[4, ir] := ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('alkatresz_nev').AsString;
    Grid_term.Cells[5, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('db_alkatresz_jo').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[6, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('db_alkatresz_as').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[7, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('db_alkatresz_ms').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[8, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_szercsere').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[9, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_beallitas').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[10, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_karbantartas').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[11, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_ghiba').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[12, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_keszjavit').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[13, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_technpro').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[14, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_anyaghiany').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[15, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_Egyeb').AsInteger);
    Grid_term.Cells[16, ir] := IntToStr(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);
    ir := ir + 1;
    ClientDataSet1.Next;
  end;
```

And here is the update code:

```
var
  ir: integer;
begin
  ClientDataSet1.First;
  ir := 0;
 // ClientDataSet1.
  while not ClientDataSet1.Eof do
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.Edit;
  {  ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('torzs_id').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[0, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('torzs_nev').AsString := Grid_term.Cells[1, ir];
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('muszak_id').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[2, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('gep_nev').AsString := Grid_term.Cells[3, ir];
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('alkatresz_nev').AsString := Grid_term.Cells[4, ir]; }
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('db_alkatresz_jo').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[5, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('db_alkatresz_as').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[6, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('db_alkatresz_ms').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[7, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_szercsere').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[8, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_beallitas').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[9, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_karbantartas').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[10, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_ghiba').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[11, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_keszjavit').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[12, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_technpro').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[13, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_anyaghiany').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[14, ir]);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('A_Egyeb').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[15, ir]);
   // ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := StrToInt(Grid_term.Cells[16, ir]);
    ir := ir + 1;

    ClientDataSet1.Post;
    ClientDataSet1.Next;
  end;
  ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0);
  ClientDataSet1.Refresh;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **OnPostError, OnReconcileError** to see if there any errors occurring during the post.
Also pay attention to the documentation:

> ApplyUpdates returns the number of errors it encountered. Based on this return value and the
>   setting of MaxErrors, successfully applied records are removed from
>   the client dataset's change log. If the update process is aborted
>   before all updates are applied, any unapplied updates remain in the
>   change log.

Comment: I guess the problem was the 0 i set to -1 and everything is ok now